# update the array of object in the react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the `react-redux`.

```
const initialState = {
    Low: [
        {
            id: 0,
            type: '',
            count: '',
            allowded: 6,
            level: 'EASY'
        }
    ],
    Medium: [
        {
            id: 0,
            type: '',
            count: '',
            allowded: 7,
            level: 'MEDIUM'
        }
    ],
    High: [
        {
            id: 0,
            type: '',
            count: '',
            allowded: 7,
            level: 'TOUGH'
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my initial state value.

After that ,

```
onChange(event, tobeupdated, id, type, noc, data) {
   let newData = { ...this.props.data };
    if (newData) {
      let data = newData[type].map((object, index) => {
        if (object.id === id) {
          object[tobeupdated] = event.target.value;
          const tobeData = newData[type];
         this.props.updateLowLevel({tobeData, type}).then(() => {
            let criteria_filled = this.disableAddbutton({ ...this.props.data }, type);
            addedRow = `new${type}RowAdded`;
            this.setState({
              [addedRow]: criteria_filled ? true : false
            })
});
}
```

This way I am updating the object values. and then replacing that whole object.

```
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: QUIZ_DATA,
      data: tobeUpdated,
    });
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

In my reducer ,

```
case QUIZ_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.data.type]: [action.data.tobeData],
                error: false,
            }
```

Now,Here what is happening when I change the lets say `type` then it adds that array of object to as a children to the previous array. so, it gets added as many as you are adding. 
SO, because of that I am not able to get that render properly.

So what Happens is ,
Low : [image]

This way gets added. So, How Can I do this ?

Can any one helm me with this ?

Comment: for once, try creating a local variable in reducer, and make it something like: `case QUIZ_DATA: {let data; data = [...state]; data.data.type = action.data.tobeData; return data}`

Comment: data = [...state]; After doing this, data is not getting the actual data it is undefiend

Comment: would you please post the complete reducer code? i mean from top to bottom. i want to see how have you handled state in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Try this out as a reducer. It spreads the content of tobeData to an array.

```js
case QUIZ_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.data.type]: [...action.data.tobeData], // the difference is here
                error: false,
            }
```

Comment: Here, to send that object I have to take   const newData = { ... this.props.data}

Comment: I not really understand you. Do you tried it as a reducer? I think it would result the data structure you want.

Comment: I added a comment to the difference. You basically put an array in an array. While in my solution the array is copied to the array with the spread (...) operator.

Comment: One thing is that , why that when I try to reset it then the initial state value always remains the filled value and not the reset to the initial state

Comment: I think I answered your question. If you like it then please accept it. And if you have further questions, then add it in a separate question with more code if necessary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648186/update-the-redux-state-in-the-reducer-having-array-of-objects/53648784?noredirect=1#comment94173128_53648784

Comment: If you have some time time then will you please check this one

Comment: Accept and upvote the answers if its solve your problem, please. You did not accept a single answer in the last couple of months if I look at your page. If you do not reward the people who help you why do you expect them to help. Read this help center article please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
[action.data.type]: [...action.data.tobeData],
```

The data you passing through `action.data.tobeData` `(eg: [1,2,3])` is the array itself.

So when you use `[action.data.type]: [action.data.tobeData]`, this will create the array of array `[[1, 2, 3]]`.

You could use `[action.data.type]: [...action.data.tobeData]`, this is called spread operator, all it's doing is basically copy all the `element` inside `action.data.tobeData` and spread it out.

You can refer to this document
[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)